# Task :react-native-reanimated:buildCMakeDebug[armeabi-v7a] FAILED react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

I have a `react-native` application, I am trying to implement `react-native-drawer` for that I have installed all the related dependency as below

[image]

but I am getting below error

I have tried almost all possible solution available those solutions are not working for me.

Any help would be appriciated.

[image]